# Why my parallel foreach loop in R takes more time then a simple for loop?

Tags: r, parallel-foreach, snow

I'm new to R , I'm trying to parallelise a nested for loop using foreach loop and doSNOW package
but the the foreach loop takes more time than a the for loop

her ‘is my code :

initialising variables

```
m=1000
n=5000
k=3
x=matrix(c(rnorm(m*n/2,0,1),rnorm(m*n/2,2,1)),n,m,byrow=TRUE)
d1 <- matrix(,nrow=nrow(x), ncol=k)
d2 <- matrix(,nrow=nrow(x), ncol=k)
centres=x[sample(1:nrow(x),k,replace=FALSE),]
```

the for loop

```
start.time1 <- Sys.time()
for(i in 1:n){
  for(j in 1:k){
    d1[i,j] <- sqrt(sum((x[i,]-centres[j,])^2))
  }
}
end.time1 <- Sys.time()
time.taken1 <- end.time1 - start.time1
```

the parallel foreach loop

```
start.time2 <- Sys.time()
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)
cl <- makeCluster(4, type="SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cl)
for(j in 1:k){
  d2[,j] <- foreach(i = 1:n, .combine='cbind') %dopar% sqrt(sum((x[i,]-centres[j,])^2))
}
end.time2 <- Sys.time()
time.taken2 <- end.time2 - start.time2

print("execution time without parall")
print(time.taken1)

print("execution time with parall")
print(time.taken2)
```

---

the results

```
# source('~/.active-rstudio-document')
# [1] "execution time without parall"
# Time difference of 0.335393 secs
# [1] "execution time with parall"
# Time difference of 9.425545 secs
```

Warning messages:

```
1: closing unused connection 34 (<-localhost127.0.0.1:11721) 
2: closing unused connection 33 (<-localhost127.0.0.1:11721) 
3: closing unused connection 32 (<-localhost127.0.0.1:11721) 
4: closing unused connection 31 (<-localhost127.0.0.1:11721)
```

Comment: The problem might be that you are adding time to load libraries too..

Comment: No it isn't i tested it

Comment: yeah I checked too. It is not making any difference. It must be the splitting task and re-merging results that takes more time then then.

Comment: is there anyway to improve it  ?

Comment: still working on it. Please give me some time :)